# Does Hibernate/JPA @Postload annotation mark the object "dirty"?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

We're using Hibernate EntityManager 3.6.10 (implements JPA 2).  I've checked the JPA spec and the Hibernate documentation but it does not appear to address this issue.

I have a number of entity objects which use @PostLoad to trim trailing spaces from persistent fields which are strings:

```
@Column(name="MY_DESCRIPTION", nullable=false, length=30)
 private String myDescription;

@PostLoad
private void trimStrings() {
    myDescription = myDescription.trim();
}
```

Will this mark the object "dirty" and generate extra saves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that will mark the field dirty and will generate an extra save.

Answer (score 2):

As Andrei mentioned, that would mark the object as dirty. If you still need to trim the value you can put the trimmed version in a transient field which is not saved, and hide the value that is saved in the database. You'll also need to update the attribute that gets saved when you update the transient value.

Alternatively, if the value shouldn't have spaces just run an update on the DB to remove all the spaces from those columns.

Comment: Tragically, the DB is all fixed-length space-padded fields, and the design is not negotiable (ugh).